# How to get all the clients connected to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Is there any command which will display list of all IP addresses currently connected to MongoDB?

I tried `db.serverStatus().connections` but it only returns total number of connections, but does not give any information about connected clients.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Previous answer to your question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808264/how-to-get-connected-clients-in-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[db.currentOp(true)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/#db.currentOp) will give you that.